# How to add standard deviation as legends in timeseries panel of grafana?

Tags: typescript, grafana, azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I have a timeseries and I am able to visualise it in timeseries panel in grafana. I want to show standard deviation in the legend but I could not find in [available calculations](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels/calculation-types/).

Is there a way to show standard deviation (along with default calculations like min, max)? I thought I will clone the built-in timeseries plugin and modify the code. But I don’t know React and typescript. Can someone help in typescript for [built-in panel](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/tree/main/public/app/plugins/panel/timeseries)?

One option is to add stats panel but I am using repeating panel/rows, so stat panels unnecessarily triggers additional queries. This reduces the performance and increases the number of hits to the database.

If it helps, I am using Azure data explorer